# Does firebase encrypt data with a unique key per account?

Tags: encryption, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So , 
I know Firebase encrypt data at rest according to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35709006/1637357).

question is do they use a unique key per account , also where are those keys stored.
This is more a compliance concern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase relies on [Google Cloud Platform's default encryption at rest](https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-at-rest/#googles_default_encryption).

Data is not encrypted with an account-specific key.

Comment: Are CMEK and CSEK solutions available also?