# Firebase/Firestore Encryption Level at rest

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking for documentation that says the level of encryption is used at rest for firebase auth and firestore data:

- Firebase Authentication
- Firestore

This [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708611/firebase-encryption-at-rest) question points to a link that says it is encrypted, here: https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy#data_encryption

However, it does not specify the encryption level.

Is the data encrypted at AES 256?  If not, what level of encryption is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore is a part of Google Cloud products and all user content stored in Google Cloud is encrypted at rest without additional action required.

As shown in the [diagram](https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-at-rest/default-encryption#layers_of_encryption), data chunks in storage systems are protected by AES256 encryption with integrity.

The same applies on Firebase Auth as the service run on Google infrastructure though it is exclusive on US datacenters.

https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-at-rest/default-encryption